# Advice to Destroy Anxiety

Tags: sources-mekorot, how-to, faith-bitachon-emunah

At times, it is possible for one’s connection to Hashem to lower a bit, resulting in a lack of Emunah and anxiety. (Shall it not happen to anyone!) What are some ways to destroy anxiety? Can you list sources in the Gemara or other books that discuss anxiety, and how to cure it? Thanks!

Comment: :הֲל֚וֹא צִוִּיתִ֙יךָ֙ חֲזַ֣ק וֶאֱמָ֔ץ אַֽל־תַּעֲרֹ֖ץ וְאַל־תֵּחָ֑ת כִּ֚י עִמְּךָ֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֔יךָ בְּכֹ֖ל אֲשֶׁ֥ר תֵּלֵֽךְ (Ok, I understand that might not be what you're looking for.)

Comment: I found this on a very  quick internet search:  https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/514028/jewish/A-Torah-Approach-to-Anxiety-Relief.htm  Haven’t had time to read it though

Comment: Are you looking specifically for sources that discuss anxiety, or are Halacha- or Hashkafa-inspired solutions from personal experience acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be somewhat controversial and sensitive but I'd like to give it anyways. If you are male, try to become shomer habris. Stop masturbation and viewing inappropiate things. After 2 weeks all anxiety is gone and you are in a spiritual blissful state.

This is my personal experience. Our sages also amplified the importance of this particular issue and it really does work. HaShem is watching you and if you remain holy, no anxiety will creep in.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Tanya's chapter 29, which discusses how to deal w a situation when one feels stagnant in one's spiritual state (timtum halev), here is a link: https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=2/13/2018             Chapters 26-28 are a very good sources too...